# When UK visa is rejected with comments "no right to appeal or right to administrative review" can I apply again immediately

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

When a UK visitors visa is rejected with comments no right to appeal or to administrative review can one apply afresh and, after how long?

Comment: You are allowed to apply again immediately.  Whether this is wise depends on your circumstances.  The usual recommendation is that it is unwise unless there was an obvious deficiency in your application that you can correct.

Comment: You need to improve the application relative to each reason for the refusal. That may be as quick and simple as immediately re-applying with the addition of an accidentally omitted document. It may be as time consuming and difficult as getting from new graduate to established in a career with a long term job, a bank account, and a home.